# @ConstructorBinding configuration not triggering validation when implementing the Validator interface

Tags: spring-boot, spring-validator, spring-properties

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `2.4.4`.

I'm experimenting with validation on Typed Configuration using `@ConstructorBinding` and without.

Here's a Typed Config that gets validated and correctly stops the app from running. It's not using `@ConstructorBinding`, but the getter/setter style:

```java
  @ConfigurationProperties("app")

  @Validated

  @Getter
  @Setter
  public static class AppProperties implements org.springframework.validation.Validator {

    private int someProp = 10;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
      return aClass.isAssignableFrom(getClass());
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
      AppProperties appProperties = (AppProperties) o;

      if (appProperties.getSomeProp() < 100) {
        errors.rejectValue("someProp", "code", "Number should be greater than 100!");
      }
    }
  }
```

The webapp is set with `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` so it all works. When running, as expected, I get this:

```
Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'app' to com.example.demo.DemoApplication$AppProperties failed:

    Property: app.someProp
    Value: 10
    Reason: Number should be greater than 100!
```

Great.
But I'm a fan of constructor injection, and I wanted to refactor this into using `@ConstructorBinding`. Let's do it:

```java
  @ConfigurationProperties("app")

  @ConstructorBinding // !!!

  @Validated

  @Getter
  // @Setter - no setters!
  public static class AppProperties implements org.springframework.validation.Validator {

    private int someProp = 10;

    // constructor!
    public AppProperties(int someProp) {
      this.someProp = someProp;
    }

    // same validation as above
  }
```

This time, the app starts. No errors. I was expecting the app NOT to run, and for me to get the same startup error, because the injected `someProp` is `0` (I haven't declared it anywhere), so clearly invalid according to my validation. If I debug the `AppProperties`, the `someProp` member is indeed `0`.

---

I did some research, but I'm too big a Spring noob to figure out why. Here's some of my findings:

- although [I agree with the Spring devs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/23733#issuecomment-711130190) that a `org.springframework.validation.Validator` should be a standalone object, meant to validate many objects, the matter of fact is that a `Validator` *is* considered when binding to a Typed Config implementing `Validator`. See here: [GitHub link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d1eb9d53ab4f13cf97ecc1684cc98894668d66c8/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java#L142-L144). That code says "If your class implements Validator, I'm going to use a special binder to when creating your bean, which will validate it".
- using the getter/setter style, you get **two** validators from `org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder#getValidators()` - JSR-303 and `Validator`, while using `@ConstructorBinding` gets you **one** - only JSR-303. Why is that? Well, because the target - my Typed Config - has no value yet when using the constructor binding: [see here the condition](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d1eb9d53ab4f13cf97ecc1684cc98894668d66c8/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java#L142-L144).
- related to the above, on ctor binding, this condition is false, thus bypassed: [condition bypassed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d1eb9d53ab4f13cf97ecc1684cc98894668d66c8/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBean.java#L267-L269).
- depending on strategy, the bean definitely gets created differently:

  - ctor binding triggers this method [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d1eb9d53ab4f13cf97ecc1684cc98894668d66c8/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBean.java#L250), and it creates a "Value Object" (not sure what that means in Spring's context)
  - getter/setter, instead, triggers this method [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d1eb9d53ab4f13cf97ecc1684cc98894668d66c8/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBean.java#L201).

---

This probably relates to the creation-time of the bean - ctor is early, setter is later. Still, at this point, this is just curiosity.

Any ideas how can I make the a constructor-bound typed configuration to be validated using the `Validator`? How would you do it instead, if this isn't the way to go?

Thanks for reading.